# Button clicks in Jade

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I'm having difficulty getting a button to execute a javascript function when it is clicked, below is my jade file

```
extends layout
block content
  - var something = function() {
  -   console.log('something')
  - }

  button(onclick='#{something()}') Click
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Where is that function at? Is that a server side function?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the function is the jade view. If I just call the function in the view (as opposed to having it called by a button click) then it logs to the console fine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With this line:
`button(onclick='#{something()}') Click`

you tell Jade that it should paste the content of the function into the value of the **onclick** attribute.

Just reference the function name:

```
button(onclick='something()') Click
```

But this won't work, because the function is only available in the Jade compile step.
After this step the generated HTML has no access to the variables which was defined in Jade.

You need to include a JavaScript file or use the script tag:

```
script.
  var something = function() {
    console.log('something')
  }

button(onclick='something()') Click
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting somewhere now, but when I do that I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: something is not defined `

Comment: Perfect, that's working now! My lack of knowledge about Jade really shone through there :)

Comment: @timaschew I've declared the script tag at the last, still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle link.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a space:

```
button(onclick='#{something()}') Click
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I did have a space in my code, it's still not working

Comment: If you open console which you used to start node.js, what will you see?