# in javascript properly escape single quote when dealing with mongodb

Tags: javascript, escaping

To use a tts method in my javascript code I wrote this code:

```
i(class="btn-left-margin fa fa-volume-down fa-2x speak-task", onclick=`responsiveVoice.speak(${word.rq}, "French Female");return false;`)
```

and the French sentence is saved to mongodb as "...jusqu'à...", that is it has a single quote.

This breaks the code obviously and I get:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

How to properly escape to prevent this and similar cases to happen?
I remember "validate input, escape output" but I don't know how!

**Edit**

If I remove the single quote and have it as "...jusqu à...", it works fine. I just found out that I don't know how properly escape all javascript related characters before saving to mongodb.
By reading forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717461/2275800), I solved my case with this improvement:

```
onclick=`let x="${word.ea}".replace(/['"]+/g, ' ');speakEn(x)`
```

but I think there must be some best practice for escaping the code in JS that I don't know, which will escape out all special characters when publishing text from mongodb (like "<" and ">", etc.). I first thought it could be escape() method, but it happens not to be the one and even deprecated.

Comment: What is `i` at the first code block?

Comment: From font awesome, it doesn't play any role.

Comment: Are you using some sort of HTML pre-processor?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer to your question, but I use PUG as template engine. Anyway I will close this question because I solved the "single quote" and now it's working fine. I will raise another question regarding the problem I recognized: that I'm not aware of the best practice for validating against injections when JS gets input data to insert to mongodb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem:

```
onclick=`let x="${word.ea}".replace(/['"]+/g, ' ');speakEn(x)`
```